# Show the output of a procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

The procedure uses the previous function to display the list of the products: num, designation and mention on the application.

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION STORE(num_produit IN INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR AS
    N INTEGER := 0;
    incre INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(qte) INTO N FROM Ligne_Fact WHERE num_produit = produit;
    IF N > 15 THEN
        RETURN 'fort';
    ELSIF N > 11 THEN
        RETURN 'moyen';
    END IF;
    RETURN 'faible';
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_PRODUITS IS
    SOME_VAR VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN
   SELECT num, designation, STORE(num) INTO SOME_VAR FROM Produit;
    dbms_output.enable();
    dbms_output.put_line('result : '|| SOME_VAR);
END;
/
BEGIN
    SHOW_PRODUITS;
END;
/
```

I am sure that all the tables are filled with some dummy data, but I am getting the following error:

```
Function STOCKER compiled
Procedure AFFICHER_PRODUITS compiled
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/4       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/56      PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
Errors: check compiler log
Error starting at line : 28 in command -
BEGIN
    AFFICHER_PRODUITS;
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.SHOW_PRODUITS is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first **major** mistake you've made is to create your objects in SYSTEM schema. It, just like SYS, are *special* and should be used only for system maintenance. Create your own user and do whatever you're doing there.

As of your question: `select` returns 3 values, but you're trying to put them into a single `some_var` variable. That won't work. Either add another local variables (for `num` and `designation`), or remove these columns from the `select`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_PRODUITS IS
    SOME_VAR VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN
   SELECT STORE(num) INTO SOME_VAR FROM Produit;    --> here
    dbms_output.enable();
    dbms_output.put_line('result : '|| SOME_VAR);
END;
/
```

Code, as you put it, presumes that `produit` contains a single record (it can't be empty nor it can have 2 or more rows because you'll get various errors).

Maybe you wanted to access all rows; in that case, consider using a loop, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_PRODUITS IS
    SOME_VAR VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r IN (SELECT num, designation, STORE(num) some_var FROM Produit) LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.num ||', '|| cur_r.designation ||', result : '|| cur_r.some_var);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then

```
set serveroutput on
BEGIN
    SHOW_PRODUITS;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compile some stored routine which calls another stored routine named AFFICHER_PRODUITS and that routine calls SHOW_PRODUITS but SHOW_PRODUITS does not compile, hence the error. (By the way, it is recommended not to create your own stored routines in the SYSTEM schema.)

SHOW_PRODUITS does not compile because of this line:

```sql
SELECT num, designation, STORE(num) INTO SOME_VAR FROM Produit;
```

It appears that you want to get the query results as a string. In order to do that, you need to concatenate the column values, i.e.

```sql
SELECT num || designation || STORE(num) INTO SOME_VAR FROM Produit;
```

Of-course if all you want to do is display the query results, using DBMS_OUTPUT, you can declare a separate variable for each column.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_PRODUITS IS
    SOME_NUM Produit.num%type;
    SOME_DES Produit.designation%type;
    SOME_VAR VARCHAR2(6);
BEGIN
    SELECT num
          ,designation
          ,STORE(num)
      INTO SOME_NUM
          ,SOME_DES
          ,SOME_VAR
      FROM Produit;
    dbms_output.enable();
    dbms_output.put_line('result : ' || SOME_NUM || SOME_DES || SOME_VAR);
END;
```

Note that if the query returns more than one row, you will [probably] need to use a [cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-F1FE15F9-5C96-4C4E-B240-B7363D25A8F1).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_PRODUITS IS
    SOME_NUM Produit.num%type;
    SOME_DES Produit.designation%type;
    SOME_VAR VARCHAR2(6);
--
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT num, designation, STORE(num) FROM Produit;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO SOME_NUM, SOME_DES, SOME_VAR;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line('result : ' || SOME_NUM || SOME_DES || SOME_VAR);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
END;
```